# If local storage is empty, how to make it display a message?

Tags: javascript

I have a local storage and I'm trying to get my site to display a message when the local storage is empty. The code I have is not working.

```
if (localStorage.length === 0) {
            document.getElementById('message').style = 'display: block';   
            } 
            
            else {
                document.getElementById('message').style = 'display: none';   
            }
```

With a div tag for the message:

```
<div class="message">MESSAGE</div>
```

I did not put this in a function within my JS file, instead just put it in my script logic. I can put it in a function, but i am not sure how i would call it.

Comment: why use getElementById?

Answer (score 2):

You use the wrong selector or need to set an ID on the div instead of a class:

```
<div id="message">MESSAGE</div>
```

Otherwise you need

```
document.querySelector(".message")
```

note the dot

---

Also make sure you execute the code AFTER the element exists.

I think this is an X/Y problem, since localStorage.length will never be 0 since it has other stuff you did not put in there.

I would do

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  let myImageArray = localStorage.getItem("myImages") || [];
  const message = document.getElementById('message');
  const toggleMessage = () => message.hidden = myImageArray.length > 0;
  const updateLocalStorage() => {
    localStorage.setItem("myImages", myImagesArray); // only one place is updating localStorage
    toggleMessage();
  }
  const addImage = imageId => {
    myImagesArray.push(imageId);
    updateLocalStorage();
  };
  const removeImage = imageId => {
    myImagesArray = myImagesArray.filter(img => img !== imageId)
    updateLocalStorage();
  };
  toggleMessage(); // initialise
});
```

and have

```
<div id="message" hidden>MESSAGE</div>
```

Comment: I have no doubt that this code works, but when i remove all items from the local storage (by using a button) when it gets to 0, it isn't showing the message. i think it's not registering it when the storage has nothing in it becasue the storage is having an issue.

Comment: no, so here is the funciton im using the remove each item from local stroage

Comment: ```function remove(element) {
    localStorage.removeItem(element);
    element.parentElement.remove();
}
```

Comment: I am using an array of images. instead of having it check local storage, i can have it check the array instead. I think that would be easier actually...

Comment: Sorry, im new at this.

Comment: If i were to do it off the array, The array would be: 
```
let images = []
```
and then it would be something like:

```
if (images == 0) {
           document.getElementById('message').innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: I have updated my code to handle an array that is stored in localStorage

Answer (score 1):

I think you just only change `class` with `id`:

```html
<div id="message">MESSAGE</div>
```

and the JS:

```js
document.getElementById('message').style.display = localStorage.length === 0 ? '' : 'none';
```